# Custom post type permalink sends to 404.php

Tags: wordpress

Hi I have created a custom post type and custom taxonomy.The custom post type page is named page-portfolio.php.I have create a loop in it in witch I am trying to link to each posts single page.For that I have created a template single-portfolio.php  but for some reason when I click the permalinks I get sent to the 404.php page.Here is my entire structure code:

```
//custom post type and taxonomy declaration
<?php

add_action('init' , 'portfolio_manager');

function portfolio_manager(){
    $args = array(
            'label' => 'Portfolio Manager',
            'singular_label' => 'Portfolio Manager',
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'supports' => array('title' , 'editor' , 'thumbnail'),
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'portfolio',
                'with_front' =>false
            )
    );
    register_post_type('portfolio' , $args);
}

add_action('init' , 'portfolio_taxonomy');

function portfolio_taxonomy(){
    register_taxonomy("portfolio-type", 
                      array("portfolio"),
                      array("hierarchical" => true, 
                                "label" => "Portfolio Types",
                                "singular_label" => "Portfolip Type", 
                                "rewrite" => true, 
                                "slug" => 'portfolio-type'
                                )
                     );
}
?>
//page-portfolio.php loop
$portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type'=>'portfolio',
                        'posts_per_page'=>'-1'
                    ));
                    while($portfolio->have_posts()): $portfolio->the_post();
                     global $post;
                 ?>
                 <li class ="item" data-type="<?php echo str_replace(" " , "" , strip_tags(get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'portfolio-type' , '' , '' , ''))); ?>" data-id="id-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                            <span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Details</a></span>
                      <?php
                        endif
                      ?> 
                 </li>

                 <?php
                     endwhile;
                 ?>
```

If single-portfolio.php is not the page template I should be creating for this page then what is the corect template?

If single-portfolio.php is the corect template then what am I doing wrong here.Why is the permalink not sending me to single.portfolio.php?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the permalinks and not with the template?

Answer (score 0):

try to rename it to single-portfolio.php

read more about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

All the best,
Marten

Comment: That's exactly the name I used and I posted that